# Data not showing up in SQL

Tags: sql, rows

I have a very simple problem, but I can't figure it out since Im new to the SQL world.  This is how my data is appearing when trying to pull it from a SQL script.

```
SUPPLIERID PRODUCTID DESCRIPTION SUPPLIERID 
-             -           -         1 
-             -           -         4 
-             -           -         3 
-             -           -         2 
2A            1       Metal Piece   -  
3A            2      Plastic Piece  -  
4A            3         Hinges      -  
5A            4         Hooks       -
```

This is my code

```
select   "PRODUCT1"."SUPPLIERID" as "SUPPLIERID",        
  "PRODUCT1"."PRODUCTID" as "PRODUCTID",
  "PRODUCT1"."DESCRIPTION" as "DESCRIPTION",
  "SUPPLIER"."SUPPLIERID" as "SUPPLIERID" 
FROM "SUPPLIER" 
FULL OUTER JOIN PRODUCT1
ON supplier.supplierid = product1.supplierid
```

if i do a LEFT or RIGHT JOIN, I only get one column of information.  How can I get all the columns to fill out in 4 rows?

Comment: Are you concerned about the blanks? how do you like your output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your `product1.supplierid` does **not** match the `supplier.supplierid`.

So there is no real joining happening between rows.. So you get a full copy of each table.

you try to match **1, 2, 3, 4** with  **2A, 3A, 4A, 5A** (*they do not match*)

You are either joining the wrong columns (*maybe you want `supplier.supplierid` with `product1.prdoductid`*) or you tables are not correctly related..

Answer (score 0):

The supplier ID does not match. If "1A" should match "1" then you should do this (SQL Server):

```
select   "PRODUCT1"."SUPPLIERID" as "SUPPLIERID",        
         "PRODUCT1"."PRODUCTID" as "PRODUCTID",
         "PRODUCT1"."DESCRIPTION" as "DESCRIPTION",
         "SUPPLIER"."SUPPLIERID" as "SUPPLIERID" 
FROM "SUPPLIER" INNER JOIN PRODUCT1
ON supplier.supplierid + 'A' = product1.supplierid
```

But you should only do this if you KNOW FOR SURE "1A" should match "1". If you're not, then they really should not match, and that's why you get that result by using `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: By the way, the "side" of the join (INNER, LEFT or RIGHT) depends on what you want to return, you should let us know what's more important: supplier or product.